# How to call specified method from component by route path?

Tags: angular

I have the following route rule:

```
{ path: 'logout', component: LoginComponent, data: { title: extract('Login') } },
```

After click I need to call method logout in component `LoginComponent`.

My link is:

```
<a class="nav-link topRightLink" routerLink="/logout">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Can't you do this in the `ngOnInit`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `LoginComponent` you have a method `logOut()` you can just call it by a click on your link like so :

`<a (click) = "logOut()">Logout</a>`

then inside the `logOut` method, you can route using a Router like so :

```
this.router.navigate(['/logout']);
```

This gives you the flexibility to do other things in as well before you route.
you must import the Router :

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
```

then inject it to your `LoginComponent`

Comment: But if I have method in another component?

Comment: you can use the @Output decorator to share that method with other components OR you can access it via a service, so you would create a service for it and inject the service where ever you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the whole component for just one method. Specially if there is no view. And no router is needed either.

Put logout() method right in the component were the `<a>` tag is:

**View:**

```
<a class="nav-link topRightLink" (click)="logOut()" >Logout</a>
```

**Class:**

```
logOut(){
    //remove the local storage content, display a message, redirect to login page, etc..
}
```

It also could be a call to a shared service method, if you wish to share that functionality in the app.

```
logOut(){
  this.sharedService.logOut();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use,

```
<a class="nav-link topRightLink" [routerLink]="['/logout']">Logout</a>
```

instead of

```
<a class="nav-link topRightLink" routerLink="/logout">Logout</a>
```

[Here is the documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)

Comment: you need to call a method? or you want to redirect?

Comment: there is a syntax error  (some quote missing) in your answer. I tried to fix the example, please tell me if my edit was not correct, so I cancel it if needed